# What is the difference installing Ubuntu on a Galaxy Nexus from a Mac rather than a Ubuntu workstation?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a Galaxy Nexus, however the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install look like there is an assumption it is being done from a Ubuntu workstation. I am doing this from a Macbook Pro. I have the `adb` and `fastboot` programs.

In step 4 it says to run the command `phablet-flash -b`.  I am assuming this is a script which uses `fastboot -b <base_addr>` to specify a custom kernel base address. What are the actual steps being used here?  Am I safe to assume I can accomplish the same thing with the following commands?

```
fastboot flash bootloader quantal-preinstalled-boot-armel+maguro.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
(wait for fastboot mode to return)
fastboot flash boot ./quantal-preinstalled-armel+maguro/boot.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
(wait for fastboot mode to return)
fastboot flash recovery quantal-preinstalled-recovery-armel+maguro.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
(wait for fastboot mode to return)
fastboot flash system quantal-preinstalled-system-armel+maguro.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the necessary rep to comment on your question, but I would have said this might help you out: [Installing Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview using a Mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259724/installing-ubuntu-touch-developer-preview-using-a-mac/)

Comment: Thanks nick, I believe the instructions listed there will work and make sense.  I will comment back if that is not the case.

Comment: When a question is answered somewhere else, please flag it as a duplicate. Thanks :)!